# SwiftUI list how to change UITableView.RowAnimation

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, transition

In UIKit we have `UITableView.RowAnimation` but how I can change default row animation in List component of SwiftUI.

Now I always have rower moving from leading edge.

I've tries `.transition(.move(.trailing))` but it does not work.